# jquery based table pagination with inline edit support

Tags: jquery, search, grid, pagination, tablesorter

This might be simple for someone who has already done something similar.

I've a simple Grid in which I render data into controls (i.e. textbox, checkbox, ...) so that the user can do **bulk editing** in the rows rendered and then hit the submit button to get all the updates in the database.

> Now, I've a working version of such editable Grid in my ASP.Net MVC2
>   proj. Next, I want to have **sorting, pagination & filter** using jQuery
>   on client side (you can assume that I'm rendering the whole grid with
>   lots of records). I can easily do this with server side coding and
>   render just one pageful of Grid but for now consider that I want to do it on client
>   side.

I've tried the some jQuery plugins - they work fine but for normal readonly text based Grids. My Grids have textbox, checkbox which user can edit and my problem is that none of these plugins **persist their edited value during search & pagination**. Or they persist it dynamically - which is not passed to the server!

For example, in this Grid the checkbox status is either not persisted across pagination:

[image]

Hope someone has gone thru this and would help me. **We try hard to keep things simple & clean.**

Plugins tried:

- [tablesorter.pager](http://beckelman.net/2008/10/23/client-side-table-sorting-paging-and-filtering-with-jquery-demo/)
- [Datatables.net](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/)

Comment: Try jqGrid, I think it has all the features that you are looking for http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: Just tested another plugin: http://www.scriptiny.com/2009/03/table-sorter/ but it won't persist the checkbox status while paging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a few popular plugins I've reviewed so far and the basic understanding (more or less) about how they would have achieved the pagination on client side, I derive that most of them -

> Cache the table rows in a variable. And they clear the 'TBODY' before
>   paging or search and refill it with the result.

So, during the postback I only get the number of rows "refilled" and not the actual table. Atleast thats what my MVC action showed me. And sometimes, it was empty!

> I conclude that though the status and values of the controls in the
>   Grid seem to be visible across paginaton, they're not in sync with
>   what is being passed during postback. I'd be happy to be wrong or if a
>   plugin does it better.
>
> **SOLUTION:** For now, I've to log the values if my checked checkbox in a
>   temp textbox which will make the values available during postback no
>   matter what the plugin does with the actual table!

Thank you.

Comment: BTW, I've confirmed the caching scenario for the "jquery.tablesorter.filter.js" - it'll mess up your tbody during postback. At best you might expect that it'll return the original tbody. These plugins are best suited for readonly / text only Grids.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this article:
http://roberto.open-lab.com/2010/01/30/javascript-grid-editor-i-want-to-be-excel/

Several of these grids give you nearly full control of which things are persisted and when.  If you want your checkboxes to persist immediately, you could add a listener on the checkbox itself that makes a call to the server.

I'm a big fan of DataTables, but I haven't used it for the specific scenario you describe.

Comment: In case you've used jqGrid - does it have a simple initializer like : $("#sortable").tablesorter(). I saw that its constructor asks too much!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a checkbox parser for tablesorter which allows you to sort the checkbox column.

I haven't tested this, but since it uses the `updateCell` method to update the cached cell contents whenever you modify the checkbox, I think it might just work along with the pager plugin.

Check out [the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/vCTHw/18/), just copy the parser code and try it along with the pager plugin.

Edit: Oops, I forgot that it will require the latest version of [tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/) from this fork on github. The reason is that the original tablesorter doesn't pass all of the extra variables to the format function: `format: function(s, table, cell, cellIndex) {}`

Comment: I guess I didn't read the part about the table using a pager as well. If you use my fork of tablesorter, [the pager](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-pager.html) has an additional option named `removeRows` which you would set to `false` to keep the tbody whole.